# How does tacrolimus affect vitiligo-affected skin and hair (re)pigmentation?

Tags: dermatology, hair, melanin, pigment, vitiligo

While tacrolimus (Protopic) creme was not created with the purpose to treat vitiligo, it is prescribed by dermatologists for that purpose and studied as such, like in [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4861566/).

The non-pigmented hairs in vitiligo affected skin treated with tacrolimus, barely or at least very slowly seem to change from non-pigmented to pigmented hairs.

Firstly, how does tacrolimus stimulate the vitiligo affected skin to start regenerating pigment cells that were absent before?

Secondly, how does the related hair (re)pigmentation work? Especially in the case of facial vitiligo vulgaris. Generally, does hair get its color from the pigment cells in the surrounding skin? Meaning, existing non-pigmented hair follicle can regrow or incorporate pigment cells from surrounding treated skin or can a vitiligo created hair follicle without pigment cells never get pigment? In what stage of a successful vitiligo treatment will it affect hair? In other words: does the old affected hair follicle need to be removed and entirely newly created from the surrounding treated pigmented skin?

Comment: What is a hair bag?